# SilverStripe loop over certain locale children pages

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm using SilverStripe [`Translatable`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-translatable) and [`Translatable-DataObject`](https://github.com/bummzack/translatable-dataobject) modules for translations on my website.

I want to loop over certain locale page children (e.g. I have 3 locales, let's say there are EN, RU and LV) on the non-default locales.

I have this piece of code:

```html
<% loop $Children %>
    $Master.Title
<% end_loop %>
```

The problem is with `<% loop $Children %>`. If I loop it like so <% loop $Master.Children %> it doesn't bring anything.

What should I do to iterate over certain locale page children on non-default locale?

Comment: One of the options is to create translation of each child page and translate its fields by accessing them with $T(Field) (assuming that you have created public function $translatable_fields() in your YourPage.php controller. But that's not elegant way, I think there should be better way to achieve this.

Comment: First: Please use $ in your loops, so <% loop $Children %>, second: you have a typo in your code example, should it be $Children instead of $Chilren (missing D)? And where does $Master come from? Any PHP code you can share?

Comment: Hi! Edited. No more typo. $Master comes from Translatable-DataObject module. It allows you to translate only desired fields (so if you do not want to translate images or similar fields, that shouldn't be translated to other languages, you could use this module and it's $Master prefix for your templates.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But without some php code and more structure (what kind of DO or page are your looping, what is translated etc..) it's hard for me to help you. You say you loop over Pages, so there will be no $Master, cause pages are translated by `Translatable` module, not by `TranslatableDataobject`. Did you look at the source code of Translatable (https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-translatable/blob/master/code/model/Translatable.php) to find a method that could fit for your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're looping over Pages you could try using Translatable's [getTranslation($locale, $stage)](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-translatable/blob/master/code/model/Translatable.php#L1333) method, to get your 'master' language. You'll have to hardcode the locale in your template. (code below is untested):

```
<% loop $Children %>
    <% with $Translation('de_DE') %> <%-- grabs the german translation and uses it --%>
        $Title
    <% end_with %>
<% end_loop %>
```

As an alternative you can write your own getter in your Controller subclass or Controller Extension) with more logic to fit your needs.